# Derivatives of delta function as a basis for distributions

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Is there some sense in which one could write any distribution as a sum of this sort?

$$A(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x)i^n\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\delta (x-y)$$

Provided that the rhs acting on a test function is convergent for all $x$.

Comment: Only if there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_n=0$ for all $n\ge N$. Otherwise it would be a distribution "of infinite order", and this cannot be, as all distributions have finite order.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Is that to ensure that it is of compact support?

Comment: No. The point is that any distribution may act only on a finite number of derivatives of the test function it is applied to. This is a theorem, called "every distribution is finite order".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro there are distributions of infinite order, for instance $\phi \mapsto \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \phi^{(n)}(n)$.

Comment: Right, but locally around any point the order must be finite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there distributions other than countable linear combinations of Dirac delta and its derivatives?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2720399/are-there-distributions-other-than-countable-linear-combinations-of-dirac-delta)